# 10 meter Led strip power supply?

Tags: led, led-strip

Hopefully easy question for those of you into electronics, but as software person bit out of my depth.

What power supply should I be getting for the following LED strip for nice even light single color strip with dimmer attached? (that's not going to blow up/burn out)

Length: 10 meter (2 joined 5 meter strips)

Color: Red

Led per meter: 60

Wattage: 14.4 per meter

Voltage: 12v

Dimmer: LED dimmer mini RF 12-24V 12A

Been checking and calculating (12v /5A? ) but so confused by watts  volts, amps starting to doubt every answer I come up with

Comment: @Transistor: I'm still kind of new to EE.SE, but I'm really beginning to feel a need for a growing _book_ of carefully crafted _pages_ on frequently asked questions, where each crafted page has been well-vetted and hammered out by experienced engineers on EE.SE and at the same time targeted by good writers who can write well towards educational content. Something as permanent as EE.SE itself is and just as applicable to common questions, but where it can replace "waving a hand towards hundreds of old questions." I'm I alone in feeling that need? (Apologies for the side-bar.)

Comment: @jonk - I think you might be asking for an electronics version of stack-overflow documentation http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/

Comment: "so confused by watts volts, amps" - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elepow.html#c1

Comment: @gbulmer: Maybe so. I need to read that better. But on first blush, it seems to be in a direction towards where I'm heading. The short moment I gave it so far does leave me wondering if anything yet exists for EE.SE, though. I'll read more and see. But if you already know, I wouldn't mind a clue about it, too. EDIT: Never mind. It seems to be for software. Oh, well.

Comment: @jonk: You're right. I think there's actually a need for LEDs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Transistor: ;) You are making me laugh. But, no! Not LEDs!! More of a cohesive, educational encyclopedia of sorts that grows over time and provides the best we can prepare on common topics of the day. LEDs would be included, yes. But I think also using BJTs and MOSFETs as switches would be yet another. Etc. Stuff that hobbyists can use to learn from and can rely upon for quality writing targeted at a level they can follow, not only to "give them a fish" but to teach them to "fish for themselves."

Comment: @jonk - I don't believe that documentation is available beyond stack-overflow, however, this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/documentation. If there *were* an electronics.se/documentation site, then their might be an LED 'page'

Comment: @gbulmer: Thanks. That's definitive. There's nothing for EE there. Oh, well.

Comment: @jonk - ask on meta how to get it started

Comment: @gbulmer: Don't know how or even where to go. But thanks, I'll look for that and probably find what you mean here. Will google it.

Comment: @jonk - when you look at the top left of the window, you will see "StackExchange", when you click on it do you see a drop down menu with "Electrical Engineering", then "Electrical Engineering Meta" below it? That is what I mean by 'meta'. Click on that EEMeta. Ask about creating documentation there.

Comment: @gbulmer: Got it! Wow. That seems more a place for people to get their bearings on moderation. I'll have to read a lot there to see how to properly frame and post such a question. Interesting. Thanks. I completely missed that before. It will help me knowing about it.

Answer (score 1):

If the strips are 14.4 watts per metre, 10 metres will be 144 watts.  At 12 volts, that requires 12 Amps, so you need a 12 Volt power supply that can deliver at least 12 Amps.

You should use several pairs of wires from the power supply to various points along the LED strips, rather than depending on the copper tracks on the strips to carry the full current.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are CV or constant current, CC with PWM or built-in dimmer control. This is a shopping question. PWM cards are avail with 10 or 15A for CV supplies. You need at least 150W.

LED strips are designed with a series R on parallel arrays of 3 or 4 LEDs in series, so dim or off is 8-9V and they are design for cars operating at 14.2V for max power where 12V is nominal brightness.
If you run in series, shop for PWM  15A cards with 24-28V power supplies

You can use an old 350W PC PSU with 12V if run in parallel fixed moderate brightness or add PWM with a dummy load for stability reasons.

No more than two parallel 5m strings can be cascaded due to bus current limits. Series requires following string end to end with power cable.

I like to use universal 150W laptop chargers with switch options for 14V, or 16V in // or 26-28V in series, if cable is long AWG16 for this application may be just enough.

*Meanwell* brand LED supplies are a good choice for online purchase for constant current supplies used in LEDs 144W / 28Vmax ~= 6A max for Margin or 144W/14Vmax = 12A max with margin if in parallel.

Depending on your budget, lots of shopping solutions, and cable drop voltage will affect brightness so must be heavy wire if long using constant voltage (CV)

Comment: These strips are strictly made to run off CV 12VDC.  CC would be a terrible idea on this type of LED strip.  Even if you somehow got it balanced, if one segment burns out, current will increase on the other segments, until another segment burns out... race condition.  Basically the converse of the problem with old style Christmas tree lights with the shorting bulbs.  It's true PWM is the normal way of dimming these, but CC doesn't enter into it even then.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  The current limiting resistors prevent a race condition and it is 1.2 Ohm/m. You aRE THINKING of something else without the resistors.

Comment: No, I'm thinking of bog standard LED strips with 3 LEDs and a resistor in series on each segment.  Those resistors prevent a race condition when supplied at CV 12VDC.  The problem if any of your 3LED+resistor segments start failing open, the resistance per metre will increase. Think through how that impacts CC operation.